# Panel application menu icon location in BUDGIE

Tags: launcher, menu, panel, budgie, button

Does anyone know the location of the panel menu icon in budgie?

I know you can change it using Budgie desktop settings but I just want to change it back to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has been answered yet. However, based on the screenshot, it looks like you're looking for the icon for Ubuntu Budgie for 20.04+ (could be 20.10).

This icon is located at `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/ubuntu-budgie-symbolic.svg`. If you run `sudo find / -iname 'ubuntu-budgie-symbolic*'` solely based on the data from your screenshot, you should find it there.

In ubuntu-budgie in focal, this is the default start menu icon, however in bionic it is `start-here-symbolic.svg` which is found in the `/usr/share/icons` folder for the currently applied theme (`Adwaita/scalable/places/` - `Pocillo/symbolic/places` - `Faba/symbolic/places`).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just enter the value `ubuntu-budgie-symbolic` into the field shown and the default Ubuntu Budgie icon will reappear

Comment: I was hopeful for a moment, but it didn't work. The budgie icon must have a location somewhere, surely?